# How to use jquery slideDown with appendTo

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, append, slideup

I am using the ajax request to get the records from database, and am appending the data in html, But I want to slide down the html when the data is append. Don't know how can I do it.

Here is the ajax method I am using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/get_messages",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {user_id: UserId},
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == true && response.messages.length > 1) {
            $("#user_" + UserId).html("");
            var Length = response.messages.length;
            //alert(Length);
            $.each([response.messages], function(index, value) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Length; i++) {
                    var NewMessage = '<div class="para-repeat inner"><h4 class="h4_"' + value[i]['user_id'] + '>' + value[i]['date'] + '</h4><h4 class="h4_"' + value[i]['user_id'] + '>' + value[i]['truck'] + '</h4><h4 class="h4_"' + value[i]['user_id'] + '>' + value[i]['name'] + '</h4><p class="h4_"' + value[i]['user_id'] + '>' + value[i]['content'] + '</p><a href="#new" class="mail-icon"></a></div>';
                    $("#user_" + UserId).append(NewMessage).show('slow');
                }
            });
            //$("#user_"+UserId).slideDown("slow");
        } else {
            //$("#One").show();
            $("#One").css("display", "block").delay(2000).slideUp("slow");
        }
    }, error: function(xhr, txt) {
        console.log("Something went wrong ", xhr.status);
    }
});
```

And my html is like:

```
        <% @new_users.each do |message| %>
                <div class="para-repeat outer" id="user_<%= message[:user_id]%>">
                    <h4><%= message[:date] %></h4>
                    <h4><%= message[:truck] %></h4>
                    <h4><%= message[:name] %></h4>
                    <p><%= message[:content] %></p>
                    <a href="#new" class="mail-icon"></a>
                </div>
                <a id="<%= message[:user_id]%>" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="getMessages(this.id)" class="expand">Expand All</a>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: The html is like:
<div class="para-repeat outer" id="user_<%= message[:user_id]%>">
      
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to slide down

```
$('body,html').animate({'scrollTop':$("#user_"+UserId).offset().top)});
```

It may help you...

for sliding up all the messages on

```
$('.para-repeat:first',$("#user_"+UserId)).siblings().slideUp().end().slideDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this (it will animate with scroll)

After

```
$("#user_"+UserId).append(NewMessage)
```

put following code

```
var container = $('body');
var scrollTo = $("#user_"+UserId);
container.animate({
    scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop()
});​
```